# How to better write using jquery to click on the periphery to close the pop-up window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to realize that a window can appear when the button is clicked, and when the click is outside the window, the window can be closed, but at present I judge it by e.target.className, but I think this way of writing is not ideal because if it is inside the window If there are a lot of objects, I seem to have to write more e.target.className to complete the requirements, so I want to find a better and more professional way of writing!

In addition, I hope that I can click the tool button repeatedly to close and open the window, but I don't know how to write it. I tried to use the toggle method but still can't achieve the effect. I hope I can get your help, thank you.

```js
$(".tool").on("click", function (e) {
  $(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (
      e.target.className == "delet_wrap" ||
      e.target.className == "consider" ||
      e.target.className == "confirm" ||
      e.target.className == "btn_group" ||
      e.target.className == "tool" ||
      e.target.className == "txt"
    ) {
      $(".delet_wrap").css("display", "inline-block");
    } else {
      $(".delet_wrap").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tool {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #222;
}
.tool .delet_wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -90px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  display: none;
}
.tool .delet_wrap p {
  text-align: center;
}
.tool .delet_wrap .btn_group {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.tool .delet_wrap .btn_group .consider {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.tool .delet_wrap .btn_group .confirm {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" class="tool">tool
  <div class="delet_wrap">
    <p class="txt">Are you sure you want to remove?</p>
    <div class="btn_group">
      <button class="consider">consider</button>
      <button class="confirm">confirm</button> 
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Have a look at [element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest). I don't know what that is in jQuery, but plain JS caught up a while ago, and can do pretty much anything jQuery used to be necessary for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need any bloatware-jquery for this, you can use combination of [element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) and [element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to check clicked element:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".tool").forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let node = e.target;
 
  //check if clicked any buttons inside the popup
  if (node.matches("button.consider"))
  {
    console.log(node.textContent);
    return;
  }
  
  if (node.matches("button.confirm"))
  {
    console.log(node.textContent);
    return;
  }
  
  //if popup element element exists as a child, the main button clicked
  if (node = node.querySelector(".delet_wrap"))
  {
    //if popup already opened do nothing
    if(node.style.display == "inline-block")
      return;

    document.body.click(); //close other popups

    //show popup
    node.style.display = "inline-block";
    //create onClick function so we can remove listener later
    const onClick = e =>
    {
      //hide popup
      node.style.display = "none";
      //remove listener
      document.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
    };
    //add listener
    document.addEventListener("click", onClick);
  }

  // stop propagation to prevent trigger document click
  e.stopPropagation();

}));
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tool {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #222;
}
.tool .delet_wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -90px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  display: none;
}
.tool .delet_wrap p {
  text-align: center;
}
.tool .delet_wrap .btn_group {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.tool .delet_wrap .btn_group .consider {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.tool .delet_wrap .btn_group .confirm {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" class="tool">tool
  <div class="delet_wrap">
    <p class="txt">Are you sure you want to remove?</p>
    <div class="btn_group">
      <button class="consider">consider</button>
      <button class="confirm">confirm</button> 
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="javascript:;" class="tool">tool 2
  <div class="delet_wrap">
    <p class="txt">Are you sure you want to remove? 2</p>
    <div class="btn_group">
      <button class="consider">consider 2</button>
      <button class="confirm">confirm 2</button> 
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
But I would like to ask you, is the example you provided currently unable to click the tool to open the window, and click the tool button again to close the window!
Can only click on the periphery to close the window?

Comment: You can move  `e.stopPropagation();` to the end of function (I've update the example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to hold these, then use `includes` to determine:

```
const className = ['delet_wrap', 'consider', 'confirm', 'btn_group', 'tool', 'txt']

$(".tool").on("click", function (e) {
  $(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (className.includes(e.target.className)) {
      $(".delet_wrap").css("display", "inline-block");
    } else {
      $(".delet_wrap").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for providing another solution!

But if there are more than 10 buttons in the window to be displayed in the future, won't my array become very long?

I don't know if this is a good practice